# Intellij Search Regex, select specific capture group

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, capturing-group

I'm playing regex with intellij for the moment and I want to know if it's possible to use capture to select all occurrence of a specific group.

```
12 330
13 450
1223 870
1213 900

regex: (^\d+) (\d+) 

and select the 
330 
450 
870 
900 

which are in the group 2
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need groups. Use

```php
^\d+ \K\d+
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/5ttTLN/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
```

Comment: Haha I know this example can be achieve with another regex, the purpose was just to know if intellij can handle capturing group selection.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure it out @MaskedHawk?

Comment: Guys, you must tell what are you are up to. Regex matches text, it does not select text.